# How to plot all the datasets on the same plot in R?

Tags: r

I have multiple datasets from which I need to plot only two variables (overs and runs ) .I am able to plot the graphs individually ,but What I need is the all the lines graphs in the same plot .I have tried the below code .

```
fi<-list.files("C:/Users/Desktop/DL/Test",full.names=T)
dat<-lapply(fi,read.csv)

    for (i in 1:length(dat))

    {

    Datasub=data.frame(dat[i])

    plot(T1$`Team1$overs`,T1$runs,col="red",type = "l")

    lines(T2$`Team2$overs`,T2$runs,col="blue",type="l")

    }
```

Comment: `lines` is the right tool for the job, but you need to put the first plot outside the loop, make an empty plot outside the loop, and only use lines inside the loop.

Comment: Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: what are T1 and T2 here please? Looks like they're something left from before. I would think you would need to use something from datasub in the lines, using the result from the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
fi<-list.files("C:/Users/Desktop/DL/Test",full.names=T)
dat<-lapply(fi,read.csv)

plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))

for (i in 1:length(dat)) {
    Datasub=data.frame(dat[i])
    lines(T1$`Team1$overs`,T1$runs,col="red",type = "l")
    lines(T2$`Team2$overs`,T2$runs,col="blue",type="l")
}
```

Comment: If this answer helped you consider accepting it so that the matter can be closed.

Comment: @user2974951 I really appreciate that you used and expanded OP's approach instead of saying "What you are doing is wrong, do it with `library(xyz)` instead"